# Grab SSL pinning certificate using Frida on iOS

Tags: ios, ssl, reverse-engineering, frida, boringssl

I have a jailbroken iPhone (iOS 12.4) that I can use to disable certificate pinning, which works great. However I want to intercept and download the certificate so I can use it directly in a proxy without needing certificate pinning.

I am quite new to `frida` and i've been playing around with both `frida-trace` and `frida` with a script, but I can't seem to import the ssl library to use some of the methods to get a certificate from an `ssl context`.

This is my current script:

```
function overrideCustomVerify() {

        var SSL_CTX_set_custom_verify = Module.findExportByName("libboringssl.dylib", "SSL_CTX_set_custom_verify");
        if (SSL_CTX_set_custom_verify == null) {
                console.log("[!] SSL_CTX_set_custom_verify(...) not found!");
                return;
        }

        // Create native function wrappers for SSL_CTX_set_custom_verify
        var NEW_SSL_CTX_set_custom_verify = new NativeFunction(SSL_CTX_set_custom_verify, 'void', ['pointer', 'int', 'pointer']);

        // Hook
        Interceptor.replace(SSL_CTX_set_custom_verify, new NativeCallback(function(ssl_ctx, mode, callback) {
                // Show "hit!" message if we are in debugging mode
                console.log("[*] SSL_CTX_set_custom_verify(...) hit!");
                console.log(ssl_ctx);


        }, 'void', ['pointer', 'int', 'pointer']));

        // It's hooked!
        console.log("[*] SSL_CTX_set_custom_verify(...) hooked.");
}
```

This logs:

> [*] SSL_CTX_set_custom_verify(...) hit!
>
> 0x112049df8

`0x112049df8` I assume is the pointer to the `ssl context`, how can I fetch the certificate from this?

Comment: Are yo aware the a certificate only contains the public key but for a server or an intercepting proxy the private key is necessary. The private key is only available on the server therefore what you want to do is not possible. If you have an app that performs certificate pinning and you want to intercept HTTPS traffic you have to break the pinning using e.g. frida.

Comment: Yes I have broken the pinning, but I wanted to proxy it on another device also. I assumed they would use the private key within the app to verify the certificate pinning, as the certificate is public anyway.

Comment: Now thinking about it, I guess they just add the same public certs inside the app to make the check :/

Comment: Possible that the cert is included in the app, but usually only a SHA-1/SHA-256 hash is generated from the received certificates (or it's public key) and then compared to a static hash in the code.